# How to send broadcast data to all clients in a muti-threaded socket server?

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, chatroom

I am currently in the process of creating a mutli-threaded chat room in python, however I am having trouble broadcasting data to all of the clients.

I am hoping to create a system where one clients sends data to the server, and the server broadcasts the data to the other clients.

What I am hoping to achieve:
     https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvG54.png

Server:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
import time

USERNAME = str(input("Enter your username: "))
MAX_CLIENTS = int(input("How many clients: "))
BUFF_SIZE = 1024
HOST = ''
PORT = 9999

lock = threading.Lock()

class Server:
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = [] #list of clients
        self.messages = [] #messages
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.host = HOST
        self.port = PORT
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        threading.Thread(self.listener()).start()
    def conn_handler(self, conn):
        while True:
            with lock:
                self.data = conn.recv(BUFF_SIZE).decode("utf-8")
                print(data)
                self.messages.append(self.data)
                conn.sendall(self.data.encode("utf-8")) #error occurs here, cannot send data to all clients
                time.sleep(.01)
    def listener(self):
        for x in range(MAX_CLIENTS):
            self.sock.listen(1)
            conn, addr = self.sock.accept()
            print("{} has connected!".format(addr))
            self.clients.append(addr)
            threading.Thread(target=self.clientthread, args=(conn,)).start()
            threading.Thread(target=self.conn_handler, args=(conn,)).start()

server = Server()
```

Client:

```
import socket
import time
import threading

BUFF_SIZE = 1024
HOST = str(input("Enter Server IP: "))
PORT = 9999

print("Connecting to {} at port {}.\n".format(HOST, PORT))

lock = threading.Lock()

USERNAME = str(input("Enter username: "))

print("""\nClientCommands:
-----------------
\t1. @SHOWINFO --> Shows server info.
\t2. @ARCIVECHAT --> Saves chat into text file.
""")

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.messages = []
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.host = HOST
        self.port = PORT
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))
        print("\nConnected to server!\n")
        print("Please press <enter> to refresh chat in order to send message.")
        _recver = threading.Thread(target=self.recver)
        _recver.start()
    def recver(self):
        while True:
            with lock:
                data = self.sock.recv(BUFF_SIZE).decode("utf-8")
                print(data)
                self.messages.append(data)
                data = self.sock.recv(BUFF_SIZE).decode("utf-8")
                print(data)
                self.messages.append(data)
                time.sleep(.01)
    def get_send_msg(self):
        self._msg_to_send = str(input("You - "))
        self.msg_to_send = "{} - ".format(USERNAME)+self._msg_to_send
        self.messages.append(self.msg_to_send)
        try:
            if self._msg_to_send == "@SHOWINFO":
                self.ShowInfo()
            elif self._msg_to_send == "@ARCIVECHAT":
                self.Arcive_Chat()
            else:
                self.sock.send(self.msg_to_send.encode("utf-8"))
        except Exception as e:
            print("An error has occured:")
            print(e)
            archiveornot = str(input("Would you like to archive the conversation in a text file(Y/N): "))
            if archiveornot == "Y":
                archive_name = str(input("Enter file name: "))
                f = open(archive_name, "w")
                for message in self.messages:
                    f.write("\n")
                    f.write(message)
                f.close()
                print("Exiting program...")
                quit()
            else:
                print("Exiting program...")
                time.sleep(2)
                quit()
        time.sleep(.01)
    def ShowInfo(self):
        print("Server Info:")
        print("--------")
        print("Host: {} | Port: {}".format(self.host, self.port))
        print("--------")
    def Arcive_Chat(self):
        archive_name = str(input("Enter file name: "))
        f = open(archive_name, "w")
        if len(self.messages) >= 1:
            for message in self.messages:
                f.write("\n")
                f.write(message)
            f.close()
        else:
            print("[!]Error, No messages were sent[!]")


client = Client()

def main():
    while True:
        client.get_send_msg()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: When accepting clients you should store the `conn` sockets in the server object. When resending the received message in server you must loop through the sockets and send the message to each (except the one you received it from)

Comment: Can you please give an example of this?

Comment: It would be just a for-loop in `Server.conn_handler()` to call `conn.sendall` for the `conn`s of all clients